# Android - how to intent to Default browser app System page?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, native

[image]

```
val intent = Intent("android.settings.HOME_SETTINGS")
```

able to go to this page but no solution for going to the default browser app page?

[image]

I would like to intent to this system page, but no information about to intent this browser list.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

- You can't do that
- If your intent is to make a user change the default browser app, you can consider [RoleManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/role/RoleManager) which was added in API 29.
- Or just guide the user to only general default app setting only.

### Details

Actually, there is a [intent action constant](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#2093) for this.

```java
 /**
     * Activity action: Launch UI to manage a default app.
     * <p>
     * Input: {@link #EXTRA_ROLE_NAME} specifies the role of the default app which will be managed
     * by the launched UI.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Output: Nothing.
     * </p>
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_ROLE_HOLDERS)
    @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION)
    @SystemApi
    public static final String ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APP =
            "android.intent.action.MANAGE_DEFAULT_APP";
```

If you just put the `EXTRA_ROLE_NAME` as a `ROLE_BROWSER` with the intent, it launches the page that you mentioned.
The `default home app` is also internally implemented in this way, you can check the [code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/Permission/PermissionController/src/com/android/permissioncontroller/role/ui/HomeSettingsActivity.java).
As you can see in this [AndroidManifest](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/Permission/PermissionController/AndroidManifest.xml;l=432), if you launch that intent it links to the `DefaultAppActivity`

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (DeviceUtils.isAuto(this)) {
            // Automotive relies on a different theme. Apply before calling super so that
            // fragments are restored properly on configuration changes.
            setTheme(R.style.CarSettings);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String roleName = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ROLE_NAME);
        UserHandle user = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER);
        // External callers might omit the user.
        if (user == null) {
            user = Process.myUserHandle();
        }

        Role role = Roles.get(this).get(roleName);
        if (role == null) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unknown role: " + roleName);
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if (!role.isAvailableAsUser(user, this)) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Role is unavailable: " + roleName);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (!RoleUiBehaviorUtils.isVisibleAsUser(role, user, this)) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Role is invisible: " + roleName);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment;
            if (DeviceUtils.isAuto(this)) {
                fragment = AutoDefaultAppFragment.newInstance(roleName, user);
            } else {
                fragment = HandheldDefaultAppFragment.newInstance(roleName, user);
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

It shows `fragment` which is suitable for the given intent extra's role name and user.
However, the problem is that it is a system API.
It means that it is not for application developers.
it is intended as an interal API for system apps.
If you try to launch the intent from your app, the app will get an exception related to Security/Permission.
So you can consider `RoleManager` which is added in API 29.
Or you can just guide the user to [general default app setting](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS) only.